# Flutter/Dart/Firestore: How can I add a list of maps to firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Sorry if this is a repeated question. I have tried searching around but have been unable to find a solution to this problem.

I have a list of maps in dart. For example:

```
List<Map<String, String>> questionsAndAnswers = [{'questions':'How many?', 'answer':'five'},
{'question':'How much?', 'answer':'five dollars'}];
```

I would like to store this list of maps into firestore and I have seen that you can manually create an array of maps but I would like to do this programmatically.

[image]

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? I've tried `_firestore.collection('Quiz').add(questionsAndAnswers);` but this hasn't been successful and I'm receiving the following error: `The argument type 'List<Map<String, String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say this is your list of map:

```dart
List<Map<String, String>> myData = [
  {'questions': 'How many?', 'answer': 'five'},
  {'question': 'How much?', 'answer': 'five dollars'},
];
```

Adding it to a

- **Collection**:

  ```dart
  FirebaseFirestore.instance 
      .collection('collection')
      .add({'some_key': myData});
  ```
- **Document**:

  ```dart
  FirebaseFirestore.instance 
      .doc('collection/document')
      .set({'some_key': myData});
  ```